# VHDL Configuration cannot find component

Tags: vhdl

The code below is not working correctly.  I keep getting the following errors:

`** Error: HA_Config.vhd(38): Component instance "HA_Inst : HA_Comp" not found.`
`** Error: HA_Config.vhd(40): VHDL Compiler exiting`

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity HA_Entity is
  port (
    i_bit1  : in std_logic;
    i_bit2  : in std_logic;
    --
    o_sum   : out std_logic;
    o_carry : out std_logic
    );
end HA_Entity;


architecture HA_Arch of HA_Entity is

  component HA_Comp is
    port (
      i_bit1  : in  std_logic;
      i_bit2  : in  std_logic;
      --
      o_sum   : out std_logic;
      o_carry : out std_logic
      );
  end component HA_Comp;

begin 

  o_sum   <= i_bit1 xor i_bit2;
  o_carry <= i_bit1 and i_bit2;

end HA_Arch;

configuration HA_Config of HA_Entity is
  for HA_Arch  
    for HA_Inst : HA_Comp
      use entity HA_Entity(HA_Arch);
    end for;
  end for;
end HA_Config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A configuration binds a component instance to a specific entity and
architecture.  The binding part in the configuration is:

```
for HA_Inst : HA_Comp
  use entity HA_Entity(HA_Arch);
end for;
```

But there is no component instance named `HA_Inst` of the component `HA_Comp`,
just a declared component `HA_Comp` in the architecture part of `HA_Arch`, thus
the error:

> Component instance "HA_Inst : HA_Comp" not found.

The `HA_Comp` is actually not used anywhere, so it could be removed.  Also, it
looks like a circular reference since `HA_Entity` is specified for use inside
itself with `configuration ... HA_Entity ... use entity HA_Entity ...`.

If the intention is to allow different implementations of `HA_Arch`, then it
can look like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity HA_Entity is
  port (
    i_bit1  : in std_logic;
    i_bit2  : in std_logic;
    --
    o_sum   : out std_logic;
    o_carry : out std_logic
    );
end HA_Entity;


architecture HA_Arch of HA_Entity is

  component HA_Comp is
    port (
      i_bit1  : in  std_logic;
      i_bit2  : in  std_logic;
      --
      o_sum   : out std_logic;
      o_carry : out std_logic
      );
  end component HA_Comp;

begin

  HA_Inst : component HA_Comp
    port map(
      i_bit1 => i_bit1,
      i_bit2 => i_bit2,
      o_sum  => o_sum,
      o_carry => o_carry);

end HA_Arch;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity HA_Comp_Entity is
  port (
    i_bit1  : in std_logic;
    i_bit2  : in std_logic;
    --
    o_sum   : out std_logic;
    o_carry : out std_logic
    );
end HA_Comp_Entity;

architecture HA_Comp_Arch_1 of HA_Comp_Entity is
begin

  o_sum   <= i_bit1 xor i_bit2;
  o_carry <= i_bit1 and i_bit2;

end HA_Comp_Arch_1;


use work.all;

configuration HA_Config of HA_Entity is
  for HA_Arch
    for HA_Inst : HA_Comp
      use entity HA_Comp_Entity(HA_Comp_Arch_1);
    end for;
  end for;
end HA_Config;
```

Comment: "The HA_Comp is actually not used anywhere, so it could be removed." I tried removing it, but then what do I put in for this line: `for HA_Inst : HA_Comp`?

Comment: If the `HA_Comp` is not used, then it is not required to make any configuration that binds it to an entity and architecture, thus the entire `for HA_Inst ... end for` is needles.  However, that is probably not the intention, so consider why the `HA_Comp` is there in the first place, and update the design to use it as intended.  The provided example code is maybe a useful template.